# Trying to intialize LVM with a 3.7 TB Hard drive

Tags: server, hard-drive, lvm

Trying to extend a barely setup LVM on my fresh install of an Ubuntu server. I am getting the following error message:

```
Device /dev/sdd excluded by a filter
```

when trying to run:

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/sdd
```

The hard drive is is a 3.7 TB, if that makes a difference

I am trying to add this large hard drive to my volume group names media.

```
$ sudo lvmdiskscan
/dev/loop0 [ 86.55 MiB]
/dev/loop1 [ <86.88 MiB]
/dev/sda1 [ 512.00 MiB] LVM physical volume
/dev/sda2 [ 931.01 GiB] LVM physical volume
/dev/sdb1 [ 512.00 MiB] LVM physical volume
/dev/sdc1 [ 512.00 MiB]
/dev/sdc2 [ <148.55 GiB]
/dev/sdd1 [ <3.64 TiB]
0 disks
5 partitions
0 LVM physical volume whole disks
3 LVM physical volumes

$ pvdisplay
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name /dev/sda1
VG Name media
PV Size 512.00 MiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
Allocatable yes
PE Size 4.00 MiB
Total PE 127
Free PE 127
Allocated PE 0
PV UUID faDFfr-czTH-kVWZ-gWSu-TfRi-GAdV-1va2vb

--- Physical volume ---
PV Name /dev/sda2
VG Name media
PV Size 931.01 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
Allocatable yes
PE Size 4.00 MiB
Total PE 238338
Free PE 238338
Allocated PE 0
PV UUID yY4bvW-O70O-rbAB-D1er-wisb-8cba-iCTSXy

--- Physical volume ---
PV Name /dev/sdb1
VG Name media
PV Size 512.00 MiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
Allocatable yes
PE Size 4.00 MiB
Total PE 127
Free PE 127
Allocated PE 0
PV UUID g1zcN5-GXDi-duxs-oGb7-DD8P-b71A-BMDMFr
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**  Could you [edit] your question and include the exact command you're typing and the full and exact error message you're getting as it's really hard to know whether you're creating a logical or physical volume,  what is going wrong, ...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `parted --list` and `cat /etc/lvm/lvm.conf`

Comment: You should use _partitions_ as physical volumes, not _disks_, i.e. `sudo pvcreate /dev/sdd1`.

Comment: You might find [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pvcreate) useful. @Melebius according to the man page "For whole disk devices only the partition table must be erased, which will effectively destroy all data on that disk. This can be done by zeroing the first sector with: "